# b43 vs linux STA

Tags: wireless

Which driver is better ?
 i've been using STA , but now i switched to b43 and i think b43 is better in performance than STA .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for supported broadcom chipsets the b43 binary packages almost always work better.  hopefully we can look forward to better open source drivers eventually (like the change from madwifi to ath5k/ath9k).  just my 2 cents...broadcom has been a thorn in the side of linux for some time.  i remember having to use ndis-wrapper to get any amount of stability out of broadcom.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's depends on your WLAN type.
In my case b43 works better.